# Scala Lift - Connect to remote MongoDB

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift, mongohq

I currently have my app running on my local machine, in Boot.scala I have:

```
MongoDB.defineDb(

    DefaultMongoIdentifier, 
    MongoAddress(MongoHost("127.0.0.1", 27017), "platform")

)
```

I've successfully deployed the app to a cloud provider, and am in the process of setting up a database @ mongohq.com

What would I need to change to enable the app to connect? I've taken a look here:

https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Mongo_Configuration

But am a little confused by the connection details provided by mongohq, all they provide is:

```
Mongo URI 
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<my_account_name>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with MongoHQ in particular, but you should be able to put something in Boot like this:

```
MongoDB.defineDbAuth(

    DefaultMongoIdentifier, 
    new Mongo(new ServerAddress("<host>", <port>)), 
    <my_account_name>, 
    <user>, 
    <pass>

)
```

Where the <*> variables are the particular part of the connection URI that were provided to you when you signed up for MongoHQ.